# Memory footprint of racket data and datastructure

Tags: scheme, racket

Has anyone got any idea if there is a function that returns the size of some datastructure,  `sys.getsizeof` in python is an example, in racket?

Answer (score 1):

There are no such functionality builtin. It is possible to write such a function using the FFI functionality, but one must know quite a bit about the Racket internals.

Is there a particular data structure, you are interested in? Maybe it is possible to calculate the size given the number of elements in it, without using a general function.

Comment: working with bit vectors and I am trying to figure out approximately how much memory a 1000000000 bit vector will take up

Comment: You are in luck! (I wrote the initial version of the bit-vector code.) Anyways, a bit-vector packs 8 bits into a byte. The bytes are stored in a byte-string. The byte-string in turn is stored in a structure which also contains a number representing the number of bits in the bit-vector. In short: n bits uses n/8 bytes plus a few words for bookkeeping.

Comment: I must further ask, why is it that using normal vectors seems to be faster than using bit vectors? I used normal vectors in the sieve of eratosthenes to generate primes up 100 000 000 and it was much faster (up to 5x faster) than when i used bit-vectors. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Booleans are represented as immediates. That is, they are represented as a single word (32 or 64 bit depending on the machine). A vector of anything is represented in memory as a number (the number of elements in the vector) followed by the elements in the vector. If a is the address of the vector, one can get the boolean simply as (in C notation)  a[1+n]  or *(a+1+n). That is (vector-ref v n) boils down to a simple memory reference (I am ignoring error checking). On the other hand a bit-vector needs to 1 memory reference to look up the byte-string.

Comment: A calculation from n to the index of the byte containing bit n. A memory reference to fetch the byte. A small calculation to get the individual bit (as a number). And finally convert the bit (as a number) to a boolean value.

Comment: That is: The advantage of bit-vector are not that they are fast, but that they use less memory. A normal vector of boolean uses n*64 bits on 64 bit machine, where as a bit-vector only uses n bits.